# how to use jsp with js?

Tags: javascript, jsp

```
function edit(var x)
{
<%

session.setAttribute("tid",x.toString());
out.println(x.toString());
%>
}
```

can i use it like this? i need to store it in session. please help!

Comment: You lost open " symbol in <a onclick=delete( <%j;%>")

Comment: but apart from that also this line is giving error. kindly help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<%
function edit(var x)
{
    session.setAttribute("tid",x.toString());
    out.println(session.getAttribute( "tid" ) );
}
%>
```

You can know more about [here](http://www.jsptut.com/sessions.jsp).

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
<%j;%>
```

with

```
<%=j%>
```

this should work

Comment: thanx got it. please help me with a new problem

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you want to print the value of `j` in line 26. Then you should use `<%=j%>` instead of `<%j;%>`

Comment: thanx got it. please help me with a new problem

Answer (score 0):

You should replace `<%j;%>` tag with `<%=j%>` to get the value of j

Comment: thanx got it. please help me with a new problem